# Make EditText clickable

Tags: java, android, xml

Good evening,
i have the following layout and i would like to make the Edit Text clickable everywhere. Also if layout_height is set to match_parent, the Edit Text clickable area works like wrap_content.

This is the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

     <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/relative"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">   

    <TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">        

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </TextInputLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView    
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative">

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

    <TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">     

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/note_content"
        android:background="@null"      
        android:gravity="top"/>     

    </TextInputLayout>
    </RelativeLayout> 
    </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

How can i make the Edit Text clickable everywhere in the Relative Layout inside the Scroll View?

Comment: To clarify: do you mean that you want a click anywhere in the layout to register with the EditText? (like if a user clicks above or below the EditText the EditText should still be selected)

Comment: Actually, the Edit Text is clickable only in the area where is located the text. I want that is full-clicable.

Comment: Isn't EditText clickable when there is no text at all?
Did i miss something?

Comment: Is clickable but the clickable area is wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand why you are wanting to do this, you could make an button with the invisible property set to true, that covers the entire layout. Then respond when user touches this invisible button.

You respond by using the EditText method called setOnEditorActionListener()

See the info on this page with the heading "Responding to action button events":
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

Answer (score 0):

In a `scrollView` you can't fill the entire view until there is content here, you are asking to make the `EditText` Fill the whole parent space left apart from the `TextView` so that you can click any part of the layout to focus on the `EditText`. Except you give the `EditText` a `layout_height` it will remain wrap since the layout is in the `RelativeLayout' which is a child for of the`ScrollView`.